# Implementation with and without volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running below code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Common_variable extends Thread{
    private boolean running = true;

    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutdown()
    {
      running = false;
    }
}

public class Thread_demo{

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     Common_variable x = new Common_variable();
     x.start();

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     in.nextLine();

     x.shutdown();
   }
}
```

Now,I have some doubt here.
When we do "Common_variable x = new Common_variable();", new thread is created that means separate stack.At that time, one object x is also created in the heap.My doubt is:

Is there just single copy of "running" variable or new thread also has one in its stack? If yes then how both threads are able to intercommunicate and update value of "running".If no and both are accessing from same memory location then what difference is made if we declare variable running as volatile.

Please clarify where I am wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with thread stacks. `running` is a field of an object, and is thus stored in the heap.

But due to performance optimizations on multi-core machines, each core can have a copy of this value in its cache: accessing the cache is faster than accessing the main memory.

And without volatile, when the main thread sets the flag to false, there is no guarantee that the other thread will see that change: the cached value won't be written to the main memory, and the thread won't re-read it from the main memory either.

`volatile` guarantees that every change to the variable is written to the main memory, and every read of the variable after that change re-reads from the main memory.

That said, you should prefer an AtomicBoolean over a volatile variable. And in that case, you should even prefer no variable at all: each thread has an interrupt flag, that you can change by [interrupting the thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). This intrinsic mechanism has the advantage that the thread won't keep sleeping once the thread is interrupted: it will exit of the sleep() method immediately, by throwing an InterruptedException, which will allow you to stop the thread immediately.

Comment: Furthermore, beyond CPU cache (which currently is spread on 3 levels), [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) allows JVM to "cache" variables. In other words, JVM may not read attribute (heap memory whatever is on central memory or CPU one) on each iteration but use a stack copy instead. `volatile` also prevents this mechanism. If you don't understand what I mean, I suggest you read about "Stack VS Heap memory" and Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

> When we do "Common_variable x = new Common_variable();"

No, seperate stack is created when you call `start()`.

You have created only one `Common_variable` object and it has a instance variable called `running` ,so if you pass this object to various threads , they will share the `running` instance variable, which could lead to corrupted data ,that's why we use synchronization to prevent corruption of our data.

As for volatile, it guarantees visibility of changes to variables across threads

read this for more http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.